# i was using selenium for web crawling and syntax error came up from getting url , help me finding the reason

Tags: python, selenium, url, syntax-error

I was using selenium for web crawling and syntax error came up from getting url

```
url = https://www.pwc.co.uk/services/economics-policy/insights/women-in-work-index.html
driver.get(url)
```

Exception

```
File "<ipython-input-9-49259ef7fb39>", line 1
url = https://www.pwc.co.uk/services/economics-policy/insights/women-in-work-index.html
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please provide your code in the question and not image, you need to pass the url as a string to the variable like so `url = "someurl/here/"`

Answer (score 2):

the url needs to be a string

```
url = "https://www.pwc.co.uk/services/economics-policy/insights/women-in-work-index.html"
```